# How to stop node movement in Neo4J?

Tags: database, graph, neo4j, nodes

When I move a node, other nodes in the graph move. Moving one node stops it from moving further. But how to stop all nodes movements together?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the nodes are locked and will not move but when you click on the unlock button (see attached screen shot), the node will move when you move the node connected to it.  There is no setting to stop all nodes movements together.

[image]